# Why variable goes wrong as "document-node()" in sub xsl:template?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Looking directly at the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="3.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="v1" select="." as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//name"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:variable name="v2" select="." as="document-node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>21</age>
    </item>
</root>
```

The question is that: variable `v1` can be declarated well, but `v2` has an error "Required item type of value of variable $v2 is document-node(); supplied expression (.) has item type element(Q{}name)".

I looked up the definition of `document-node()`  in w3c xpath document, it says "document-node() matches any document node." [2.5.5.2 Matching an ItemType and an Item](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#id-matching-item). I still can't understand why `v2` is wrong with type `document-node()`.

I have make a online test [demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVL)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not a `document-node()`, it's an `element()`. Use `element()` instead. `<xsl:template match="/">` matches a `document-node()`, and `<xsl:template match="name">` matches an `element()` node.

Comment: Which are document node except root node?

Comment: @cmf41013, I am not sure why you expect an element node to be also a document node, perhaps the type hierarchy documented in the diagram in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-31/#types-hierarchy helps.There you can see that `node()` is a common base type for e.g. `element()` and `document-node()` (as well as `attribute()`, `comment()` and others). As for the definition of document nodes, see  https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-31/#DocumentNode

Comment: Because I translate "OMML" to “MathML”, then translate the  “MathML” to SVG. I want to treat the intermediary "MathML" as a document-node. The "Document Nodes"  looks like it should be plural form, which nodes belong this type?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Sorry, I can't read the second link's content in a short time.

Comment: Before finding my quesion, I just thought that the `document-node()' refers specifically to the root node. Now I'm confused.

Comment: @cmf41013 Of course you're confused, if you haven't got time to read up about the concepts of the language then you will be confused about them; you'll make guesses about words mean, those guesses will become fixated in your view of how things work, and it will be very hard to correct your mental model later.

Comment: @MichaelKay, Hmmm, I know the answer is in the link [https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-31/#DocumentNode](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-31/#DocumentNode), The rest of my question is the English.

Comment: @cmf41013, perhaps ask that problem about treating intermediary results as document nodes as a separate questions, with minimal but complete details to illustrate the problem. In your sample in this question you have matched with `match="name"` on an element and selected it directly with `select="."`, an element is not a document-node so that attempt to use `as="document-node()"` has to fail.